# How to show new line in angular line1↵line2

Tags: angular

my json looks like this (i can see it like this in chrome console.log)

```
Line 1 ↵ line 2
```

I need my html to print like this

```
Line 1
line 2
```

i'm trying like this

```
<address [innerHTML]="store.address"></address>
```

but it all prints out on one line.

Answer (score 1):

You should try wrapping [innerHTML] in a `<pre></pre>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Use `pre` tag or css:

```
address{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
p.c {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p class="c">
This is text 1.
This is text 2.
This is text 3.
This is text 4.
</p>
```

Use from:

```
<p class="c">
This is text 1.
This is text 2.
This is text 3.
This is text 4.
</p>


p.c {
  white-space: pre;
}
```